# my app is sending an XML file to a server: need some guidance on writing a PHP script to parse the XML file

Tags: php, iphone, xml

So my iPhone app sends a shopping cart in a XML file to a URL through POST. Here is the line of code that does that

```
NSString *pathToSerializedCart = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"serializedCart.plist"];
NSString *shoppingCartString;
NSData *serializedData;
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathToSerializedCart])
   {
    NSLog(@"ERROR:\nCouldnt find serialized cart in documents folder.");
    return;
   }


    serializedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToSerializedCart];
    shoppingCartString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:serializedData
                                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", shoppingCartString);
    [shoppingCartString release];


    //==========================================================================


NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                           returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] 
                          initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
[returnString release];
```

Now what Id like to do is put a script on the server in the file `welcome.php` so that the contents of this XML file are echoed to the browser.

I've looked at many examples but they all talk about the situation where the XML file is present in the same directory as the PHP file on the server. I haven't been able to find examples of PHP code that actually is evoked from an app.

Could someone please point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** After seeing your full objc, I *think* the POST value name in question is `userfile` and I've updated the code below.

In PHP, the filename location of your uploaded file will reside in `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`.  It is recommended to `var_dump($_FILES)` so you can understand how PHP treats the uploaded file.

The function `file_get_contents()` will read that temporary filename and return its contents as a string, which you can load into DOMDocument, as in the last bit of code below..

### Recommended reading: [PHP docs on the `$_FILES` superglobal array](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.files.php)

You'll need to retrieve your XML data from the `$_POST[]` superglobal, and then you can parse it with `simplexml_load_string()`.

```
// Sorry I'm unfamiliar with objC, so I can't glean the actual POST 
// value name from your code
// UPDATE misunderstood. the uploaded file is in $_FILES
// indexed by the POST key name.

// In development you can inspect your POST...
// To see the contents of your POST in PHP, do:
var_dump($_POST);
// Also check the contents of $_FILES
var_dump($_FILES);

// Your file is stored in the temp directory 
$xmlfile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

// Load it with SimpleXML
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
```

Or instead of SimpleXML I usually prefer the more flexible PHP [DOMDocument](http://us.php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php) library:

```
$xmlfile = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML(file_get_contents($xmlfile));

// Now parse it as necessary using DOM manipulators
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName("sometag");
foreach ($tags as $sometag) {
   // whatever...
}
```

Comment: what exactly is postName? Is it the file that was sent in post from the app or what is it exactly? Thx

Comment: @user657514 See changes above. I thought the XML was posted as a string, not uploaded as a file.  POST has to be a key/value pair and `postName` refers to the key.  If uploaded as a file, the file will have a temporary name accessed via `$_FILES[]`

Comment: Ive modified my post above. I now have the complete method of Objective C.

Comment: Im sorry. I still dont get it. Im new to PHP and server side programming. Is there any way you could simplify this?
Thanks

Comment: @user657514 More updates above. I think `userfile` is the POST key name you'll be needing.

Comment: I tried that code and Im getting the following on my url:array(0) 
{ } array(0) { } 
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in /home/content/35/7602435/html/iOS_Files/welcome.php on line 10

Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML() [domdocument.loadxml]: Empty string supplied as input in /home/content/35/7602435/html/iOS_Files/welcome.php on line 10

Comment: @user657514 If those two arrays are empty you have not posted your files to PHP from iOS.  Just test on a plain local XML file using `$xmlfile = /path/to/your/xmlfile.xml;` then run the rest.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry. This is not working for me. Thanks for your help, but unsuccessful.